# Enigmatic TypeError with QThread usage

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I have a QThread which runs, but will often need to be killed, then recreated. The problem is I'm getting an untraceable TypeError that pops up and I have no idea what's causing it. I presume I'm not exiting the thread properly or destroying it properly or some such sillyness, but I just haven't a clue what's causing it. Here's some code snippets:

Here's the code together:

```
class getHistory(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.killSwitch = 0

    def kill(self):
        self.killSwitch = 1
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        try:
            for x in theloop:
                hist = QTreeWidgetItem()
                hist.data = dataStuff
                self.emit(SIGNAL('histItem'), hist)
                if self.killSwitch == 1: break                
        except: pass
        self.emit(SIGNAL('string'), 'done')
        return

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, args):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.runTheThread()

    def doFunction(self, string):
        if not string == 'done':
            doThreadStuff
        else:
            doFinishedThreadStuff

    def runTheThread(self):
        self.theThread= getHistory()
        self.connect(self.theThread, QtCore.SIGNAL("string"), self.doFunction)
        self.theThread.start()
```

Then to try to kill it before looping, I kill theThread with **self.theThread.kill()**

All the proper things as far as killing the thread appear to be happening, except, if the thread is killed and restarted fast enough, I'll get an untraceable error:

**TypeError: doFunction() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)**

Also, on a slightly related note, is it wise/smart/right to check if a thread is done by emitting a string such as "Done" that is picked up by *doFunction*, or is there a better way to do it?

As doFunction is part of a Qt application, the two parameters are self, string. The code works until it is spammed, really, and only then does it present the error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as error states clearly: You are sending self.doFunction just one parameter (the string "AllDone" in this case):

```
self.emit(SIGNAL('string'), 'AllDone')
```

but, I'll take a wild guess (since you didn't share the definition of doFunction) that it is defined as taking two parameters. So, anytime you emit the "string" signal you are bound to get that error.

As for the signal, if it's sole purpose is to shout that the thread is completed its run, QThread already has a "finished()" signal that is emitted when run is completed. Just use that.

On a side note: If you are using PyQt4.5+ consider using [new-style signal and slots](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html). They are more pythonic.

Comment: @Cryptite: OK, i might jump to conclusions. Looking your post closely, there are more problems. You don't initialize killSwitch in __init__. And you are accessing it in run(). Which should give you an AttributeError, but you are using a bare except clause which captures all exceptions and it catches that error then passes. So your loop should run just once. Bare except is almost never a good idea. And in your doFunction you are checking for "done" but you are emitting "AllDone". Is it *really* the function you are using? Plus, I don't think you need a return statement in run().

Comment: Me oh my, I actually had all those things in there and named correctly, but I went so far obfuscating code that I accidentally misled. I am in fact initializing killSwitch in the init, and the catch is for 'done' on both ends; didn't mean to type AllDone in there at all. I think I just saw a 'return' in a thread somewhere and was trying it, but I can certainly remove it. Original code is updated and merged together so you can see it all better; also put in some example Qt stuff so it looks more sensical.

Comment: @Cryptite: Are there more "string" emit's? Probably in doThingsHere()? Looking at your code, I think there should be. Otherwise doFunction wouldn't make any sense. Because like this you could only emit "done". Maybe you emit the "string" without any parameters. That might cause that error.

Comment: Right, there are. Guess I didn't think that might be the problem, as they are not emitted strings, but rather emitted QTreeWidgetItems. I suppose that could be the issue, huh. Updated the original post.

Comment: @Cryptite: No, with "string" I meant SIGNAL("string"). If you are emitting this signal (or any other signal that's connected to doFunction) without any parameters, that would cause your error.

Comment: Ah, no, I'm not. That's why I'm led to believe that something isn't getting closed right. I checked the whole program, and while there are many signals being thrown about, none of them are specifically the 'string' signal except for in this function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3671/discussion-between-avaris-and-cryptite)